# SELECT statements - add additional column to result set

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I change this code to see both column A and D in the result?

```
SQL> SELECT A FROM R WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT D FROM S WHERE S.D=R.A AND S.C=R.B);
```

Result:

```
A
----------
1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Select 
  A, D
From
  R
    Inner Join
  S
    On S.D = R.A And S.C = R.B
```

Comment: thanks , Is there any possibility to have both A and D in output without using Join?(just have 2 select statements )

Comment: @user1837225, no. Joins are highly efficient so I wouldn't worry about using them. It's what the database is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT R.A, S.D
FROM R
INNER JOIN S ON S.D = R.A AND S.C = R.B
```

Comment: thanks , Is there any possibility to have both A and D in output without using Join?(just have 2 select statements )